# Bootstrap not working with ruby

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have tried everything and I just cant get my navbar in bootstrap to work. 
I am using a up to date version of ruby and rails [version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvFxp.png)

I have the gems the github tells me to put in my code

[Gems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAGj0.png)

and its says that they are being used

[used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHLMv.png)

I changed my application file from application.css to a scss file and got rid of all the require statements.

[scss file change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ljJ.png)

I updated my application.js file the way they told me to.

[js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWc5E.png)

but when I try and put this boostrap header in my file

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuJVE.png)

I end up with this

[rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WudHD.png)

instead of this

[from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEyJc.png)

If anyone could help it would be appreciated. I have done everything I could think of.

Comment: By posting all of these links to images you have doomed this question to become extremely temporary. As soon as those images are deleted your question no longer has any actual content.

Answer (score 2):

I recently done a project in ruby on rails with Bootstrap 4 beta 2, here are my setup:

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

*app/assets/javascripts/application.js* (The sequence are important)

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

*assets/stylesheets/application.scss*

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

For more details, go visit [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

## HERE IS THE UPDATE (refer to [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass))

1. Generate new rails app `rails new bootstrap4test`
2. `bundle install`
3. Scaffold a simple blog with text `rails g scaffold Blog content:text`
4. Database Migrate `rails db:seed && rails db:migrate`
5. Add gem into `Gemfile`

   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
   gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
6. rename `app/assests/stylesheets/application.css` to `.scss`
7. remove everything in the `application.scss` and add these

   // "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap";
8. Now, add another gem `gem 'jquery-rails'` into your `Gemfile`
9. `bundle install`
10. in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` add 2 lines

    //= require jquery
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets

Your `application.js` should look like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

11. Then start server `rails s` and go to `http://localhost:3000/blogs`
    [image: Works]

Tested on Mac, ruby: `2.4.2`, rails: `5.1.4`

Comment: that didnt work for me either. copied everything you posted to a new app and it still came out the exact same as when I tried it the first time

Comment: try read the doc from `bootstrap-sass gem`: [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), If I have time later, i try to make 1 and test.

Comment: @EmmanuelDwayneJohnson I have tested the latest one, check my editted post, I follow strictly through the documentation by `bootstrap-sass` and it works. I tested my build with class `btn btn-danger` it shows the button in red. If following the step doesnt work, try my [github repo](https://github.com/superoo7/rails-bootstrap). Clone it and start using it

Answer (score 0):

You should need to include `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` before `@import "bootstrap"`. do not know if `rails-ujs` includes both but, you might also want to require `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` inside `application.js` file.

*assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```

*assets/stylesheets/application.scss*

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

*views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

below is an excerpt from my working rails+bs setup.

Comment: I tried what you told me and I just get this error message    
When I take the sprockets import off and restart the server and reload the page... I dont even get a working button any more and noting is rendered but a button that doesnt work any more (This is the error message)                               
 Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index
Showing /Users/emmanueljohnson/Desktop/testboot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.

Comment: add `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to your gemfile -))

Comment: that didnt work either. even tried making a new app and putting gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' and it still didnt work. All i got was the words just jumpbled next to each other.

Comment: check gist below. also delete precompiled assets/cache files 

https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/01b42a5eaeef6615d4a4b2a9bc42a436